# Bootstrap issue with Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, rubygems

I am trying to implement bootstrap to my app and having issues when I try to implement some modals from bootstrap.

Created my app with using following command;

```
rails new HR-app -J -C --database=postgresql
```

My gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.1'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

environment.js file

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
  environment.plugins.append('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
module.exports = environment
```

application.scss file

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

application.js file

```
import 'bootstrap'
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
```

example I took from bootstrap and index file of my scaffold;

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[And this is how it looks;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN2sF.png)

It is not desired look of modal and also it is no functional (no error). You can see the live demo of the modal here. getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal –

How can I implement the modal as live demo from bootstrap.
Any help will be appreciated! 
Thanks :)

Comment: It can be useful. (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-a-ruby-on-rails-application) Right know your question is unclear. What do you want? Is there any error messages when you run? Or is this not the desired look of modal and you are trying to change it?

Comment: Hi Semih, thanks for your reply.
It is not desired look of modal and also it is no functional (no error). You can see the live demo of the modal here.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Hi @AliİMAMOĞLU I'm afraid your question is too broad. If you came here to seek help, you have to be more specific. If something is wrong with the styles of your modal window, then you might want to google for how to fix problems with CSS. If there is a JS problem, then there usually should be an error in the browser console.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MishaSlyusarev. I am new at development and I thought someone might had the same issue before. That's the reason I posted my question.